# I am getting error while doing make GCC(Makefile:4999: recipe for target 'configure-stage1-gmp' failed)

Tags: gcc, g++, gmp, mpfr, mpc

These are the steps i followed for installing GCC

1. Downloaded & extracted GCC, GMP, MPFR, MPC(latest versions).
2. renamed GMP,MPFR,MPC without versions and moved GMP, MPFR, MPC to source folder of GCC
3. took path of GCC and exported library "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"
4. took path of GMP and configured and installed (./configure ; make ; make check ; make install )
5. took path of MPFR and configured and installed (./configure ; make ; make check ; make install )
6. took path of MPC and configured and installed (./configure ; make ; make check ; make install )
7. GMP, MPFR, MPC configured and installed successfully
8. created directories gccbuild & gccbin outside GCC
9. took path of gccbuild
10. configuring GCC
11. sudo ../gcc-6.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/GCC_project/gccbin --enable-languages=c --program-suffix=6.3.0
12. configure completed successfully but when doing "make" i am getting the following error

    ```
    configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first
    Makefile:4999: recipe for target 'configure-stage1-gmp' failed
    make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-gmp] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/GCC_Project/gccbuild'
    Makefile:23312: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
    make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/GCC_Project/gccbuild'
    Makefile:919: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    ```
13. i have tried "make distclean" before make, again iam getting same error

Comment: Where did you get these instructions from? They suck... Some random hints: don't use sudo for anything but make install, don't build gmp/mpfr/mpc yourself (the whole point of putting them in that specific place is to let gcc handle them). You probably shouldn't mess with LD_LIBRARY_PATH either.

Comment: could u provide any instructions / procedure